# SELECT Filed name from sql table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table Master in my database with field

```
    Column Name       Data Type 
    ===========     =============

    Empno          varchar(10)
    Surname        varchar(10)
    ShiftDiffInd   varchar (1)
    PrevEmpGrossy  money
    NonTaxYtodate  money
```

And I want to take field name from this table only these two field `'ShiftDiffInd'  'NonTaxYtodate'` . Not Value of this field, So how can i do that

I want my return Like this

```
==============
ShiftDiffInd
NonTaxYtodate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where 1=1
    and TABLE_NAME = 'Master'
    and COLUMN_NAME in ('ShiftDiffInd','NonTaxYtodate')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
   syscolumns.name as [Column]
from 
   sysobjects, syscolumns 
where sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
and   sysobjects.name = 'Master'
and (syscolumns.name = 'ShiftDiffInd' or syscolumns.name = 'NonTaxYtodate')
order by syscolumns.name
```

Comment: I want to display ShiftDiffInd, NonTaxYtodate these two field name only not value of that field

Comment: i change the question last line that the result i want

Comment: No problems, please accept whichever answer resolves your issue so your acceptance rating goes up :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'ShiftDiffInd' as ShiftDiffInd, 'NonTaxYtodate' as NonTaxYtodate , * FROM Master
```

Comment: this will return value with field name form the table that i dont want

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstand your problem previously, try with below query, you get the expected result:

```
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME=OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('Master'))
AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('ShiftDiffInd','NonTaxYtodate')
```